# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect when running Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i started using python and jenkins not so long ago and i have come to a step that i don't know how to fix
when i am running a code in Jenkins Groovy to execute something on my system, i get the following error:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

When i run the code locally, not through Jenkins, it works and executes fine.

i tried reconfiguring the virtual environment in pycharm. i also tried a different python version
i expect when i run the requested pipeline to be executed

Comment: It would be useful to put a brief part of the code of your pipeline and the part where you get the error message because this problem can come from an awful lot of places.